# Where can I find a good example of Open-Flash-Charts and Java

Tags: java, grails, plugins, groovy, charts

There are a handful of open-flash-charts tutorials on the web, mostly php from what I can see.  I know there is a Java helper class, but I haven't found documentation or examples.

The helper library is also includes in the ofcharts grails plugin.

Java/Groovy or Grails suggestions welcome.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the single best sources I have found on it is [here](http://www.ofc2dz.com/)

From the site: "This site is now mainly used to post examples, help and patches for users requesting help in the OFC2 forum which I occassionally haunt."

Has proven invaluable in my developing Java/Grails charts with it. Bear in mind that you need to do little else to make the charts work than to generate JSON. To that end Grails is ideal - however what you will spend a lot of time working on is structuring that JSON data.

The linked site provides the most detailed JSON API documentation that exists for the different chart types OFC supports.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The API documentation is surpisingly hard to find.  It's a red flag to me that there aren't more documentation or tutorials or answers on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Java API reference open source project hosted on Google Code:

http://code.google.com/p/jofc2/

This is the code embedded in the Grails plugin I've been using so the documentation has helped a ton!